# MySQL connector C++ in MSVC 2015 debug mode std::bad_alloc occurs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mysql-connector

thank you for your attention in advance.

I am writing DB program using MySQL connector C++. This works well in MSVC 2015 release mode but does NOT in MSVC debug mode.

My Environment :

`Windows 10 Pro 1607`, `Visual Studio 2015 update 3`, `MySQL connector C++ 1.1.8`

My Source :

```
void dbConnect(sql::Connection* conn, sql::Driver* driver, char* host, char* id, char* pw, char* schema)
{
    conn = driver->connect(host, id, pw); // std::bad_alloc occurs in debug mode
    conn->setSchema(schema);

    sql::Statement stmt = conn->createStatement();
    ...
    ...
}
```

As looking at line 3, function `connect()` does NOT WORK well. This work well only in release mode. In debug mode, `std::bad_alloc` occurs.

I get MySQL connector C++ 1.1.5 from MySQL homepage. I found debug library in it. If I use this debug library, function 'connect()' DOES WORK WELL. I CAN make sure that source code is correct.

My Question :

1. Can I solve this through `Configuring Visual Studio 2015 options`?
2. How CAN I `build MySQL connector C++ 1.1.8` in Visual Studio 2015? Although I follow some tutorial, it does now work.